# Unbound Local Error: Local variable 'input' referenced before assignment, Help please

Tags: python

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self,model,make,speed):
        self.__model = model
        self.__make = make
        self.__speed = speed

    def accelerate(self,speed):
        self.__speed = speed + 5

    def brake (self,speed):
        self.__speed = speed - 5

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.__speed


def main():

    speed = input("Enter your cars current speed:")
    make = input("Enter your cars make")
    model = input("Enter your cars model")
    input = input("Enter 1 to accelerate , 2 to brake, ")
    car = Car(model,make,speed)



    if input == 1:
        car.accelerate(speed)
    elif input == 2:
        car.brake(speed)

    self.__make = make
    self.__model = model
    self.__speed = speed

    speed1 = car.get_speed()
    print("Your cars make is:", make)
    print("Your cars model is:", model)
    print("Your cars speed:", speed)

main()
```

I don't know why its throwing an error: line 19, when I ask for speed input.

Comment: Add the traceback message, that makes it easier to spot.

Comment: `input = input(...)` -- no. Do not name a variable `input`. When you do that you're creating a local that shadows the _function_ named `input` so that function can no longer be accessed.

Comment: You have defined ```input``` as a variable. And you are accessing it before assignment. So an error. So don't use ```input```` as a variable because it is an inbuilt function. Instead, do ```inp=input(...)```

Answer (score 0):

This line makes `input` a local function variable, shadowing the `input` function.

```
input = input("Enter 1 to accelerate , 2 to brake, ")
```

When python compiles a function, it turns local variables into slot indexes in the function object for speed. `input` is now a local variable for the duration for the function body. It can't also be the global "input". The solution is to use a different name for the variable.

```
def main():

    speed = input("Enter your cars current speed:")
    make = input("Enter your cars make")
    model = input("Enter your cars model")
    accelerate_or_brake = input("Enter 1 to accelerate , 2 to brake, ")
    car = Car(model,make,speed)
```